# Ngfor binding issue

Tags: angular

I have a click event where I will display some block when `ngIf= true`. The button responsible for click event is placed inside `ngFor` loop as this needs to be displayed for each row. When I click on this button all the rows are collapsed with the block. how to write the wrote to open the clicked row block only, please help.

I tried to check indexes which didn't worked

```
<div class="fatca-collapse">
<div class="fatca-head-row">
<span click = (allOpen)> + </span>
<span>one</span>
<span>one</span>
</div>
<div class="fatca-body-row" *ngFor ="let data of gridViewData" >
<div class="fatca-body-heading">
    <span (click)="segmentShow = !segmentShow">+</span>
    <span>{{ data.taxResCrty.codeValueDispVal }}</span>
    <span>{{ data.taxResCrty.codeValueDispVal }}</span>
</div>
<div class="fatca-body-text" *ngIf = "segmentShow">
    <span>{{data.reviewStsDt}}</span>
    <span>{{data.taxResStsUpdBy}}</span>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `click = (allOpen)`

Comment: I guess what you want to do is `(click)="allOpen()"`

Comment: Thank  you, this has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

In that case segmentShow can't be a boolean but an array of booleans, each per data, so you can change the template in the next way:

```
<div class="fatca-body-row" *ngFor ="let data of gridViewData; let index = index" >
<div class="fatca-body-heading">
    <span (click)="segmentShow[index] = !segmentShow[index]">+</span>
    <span>{{ data.taxResCrty.codeValueDispVal }}</span>
    <span>{{ data.taxResCrty.codeValueDispVal }}</span>
</div>
<div class="fatca-body-text" *ngIf = "segmentShow[index]">
    <span>{{data.reviewStsDt}}</span>
    <span>{{data.taxResStsUpdBy}}</span>
</div>
```

You just add the index in ngFor and then change the segmentShow to work with the index

In the component, segmentShow must be initialized as an array of booleans:

```
segmentShow = [false, false, false]
```

The number of items depend of the number of items the gridViewData has, so if it has 8 elements, segmentShow must have the same 8 elements initialized as false.

Comment: I have implemented the above code but see below error, I even added +1 to index which didn't worked.   Error = "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". Can you please check this?

Comment: I have changed "let index = index" to "let index of index" and tried again, which shows an error as "Cannot read property '[object Object]' of undefined".

Comment: Did you changed the segmentShow from boolean to an array of booleans and initialized? I'm gonna edit the answer with an example

Comment: segmentShow = [false, false, false], this is dynamic data. We are not sure how may values will the data contain. so I can't write particular number of false's in the array. could you please check about this.

Comment: In that case once you get the data, you can make a forEach of the data and make a push for each data in segmentShow. There would be another way in case your data has id per element, let me know if that's your case